# Odoo 8 - Wizard not opening

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I'm currently building a module which needs a wizard opening from a button.
The problem is that when i click on this button, nothing happens except 2 lines in the console :

```
"POST /web/action/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"POST /web/dataset/call_kw/stock.move/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here are the declaration of button, action and wizard :

```xml
<button string="Créer un colis" icon="terp-accessories-archiver+"
                name="launch_split_into_wizard" type="action"
                attrs="{'invisible':[('state','=','done')]}"/>

<!-- WIZARD -->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="split_livraison_into_wizard">
    <field name="name">split.livraison.into.wizard</field>
    <field name="model">stock.livraison.split.into</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Split Moves">
            ...
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<!-- ACTION -->
<record id="split_livraison_into" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Gestion des colis</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">stock.livraison.split.into</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

I've tried the official tutorial "Building a module" from odoo.com, but that didn't work. 
I don't find a solution working for **Odoo 8**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name for buttons with `type="action"` should be a ref to action. F.ex.

```xml
<button string="Créer un colis" 
    icon="terp-accessories-archiver+"
    name="%(your_module_name.split_livraison_into)d" type="action"
    attrs="{'invisible':[('state','=','done')]}"/>
```

Where `your_module_name` - name of module where described action.
`split_livraison_into` - id of action

Comment: Thanks, i thought the %()d was no longer used in Odoo 8, but it worked.